# mongo map objects into array just an array of object ids

Tags: mongodb

I have this query :

```
var $match = { isTask: { $ne: true }};
var $project = {_id: 1} ;
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([{ $match }, {$project}])
```

Returns:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("1...")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2...")
}
...
```

What I want is actual an array of object ids like this:

```
[ObjectId("1..."), ObjectId("2...")]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nc9L_xyrzeS)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "ids": {
        "$push": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```